# Angular issue with data -ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a init function for rate functionality

This is working fine

```
<div data-ng-init="rating = 5">
```

But rating values are dynamic ,

```
<div data-ng-init="rating = {{ datasourcelist.rating }}">
```

But this is throwing error

```
(Error: Syntax Error: Token 'datasourcelist.rating' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 13 of the expression [rating = {{ datasourcelist.rating }}] starting at [datasourcelist.rating }}].)
```

Please help ,

Comment: Just do `rating = datasourcelist.rating`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use angular directives you do not need to put double brackets so

```
<div data-ng-init="rating = datasourcelist.rating">
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

`{{ .. }}` is called **interpolation**, which will transform the model value to a string. It returns a **string**.

`data-ng-init="rating = {{ datasourcelist.rating }}"` is just like assigning a string to the model object `rating`.

What you need is object assignment:

```
data-ng-init="rating = datasourcelist.rating"
```